# C++ Point Cloud Library PCL. Try to add two points

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have just started to work with the Point Cloud Library (PCL). I include it,

```
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
```

and define three points,

```
pcl::PointXY pA, pB, pC;
pA.x = 1;
pA.y = 2;
pB = pA;
```

Why isn't the +operator overloaded? If I try

```
pC = pA + pB;
```

I get a compilation error. It seems like such a basic operation, and so I took it for granted that all basic operations would be defined, or have I missed something?

I found a filed called "point_operators.h" in an older version of PCL (1.6). This file defines the basic operations I want. However, in my newer version (1.9), this file is empty. How come?

Thank you!

Comment: You should add the compilation error. Otherwise I do not know why you got downvoted here.

Answer (score 1):

As for mathematical operations between points, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363587/doing-math-with-pcl-pointxyz-structs).

IMHO, the point types in pcl are not used to represent vectors but for **physical points** in 3D world. It does not make much sense (at least to me) to add two physical points together. *What are you expecting when you add a point sampled from a desk to a point sampled from your TV?*

Though [combinations of points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) do exist, I guess the backgrounds are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to merge point clouds.
I recommend following the tutorial in this [Link](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/concatenate_clouds.php)